# How many String Objects created by following statement in Java

Tags: java

My question is how many String Objects will be created by the following statement?

```
String a="good"+"luck";
```

I know about String Constant Pool. But I want to ask will just literal create object in String Constant Pool?

Is there 3 Objects?

```
1: good
2: luck
3: goodluck
```

If there is three object then where will go `1, 2` object. **will JVM clean? and when JVM will remove object from String Constant Pool?**

Comment: @Suresh can you ans please how many object? and when JVM will clean?

Comment: There one String object "goodluck" as the compile does constant inlining however if you put this in a main() it will have created around 10,000 Strings to run your program.

Comment: The string will be cleaned up when the class is unloaded, which is most likely, never.

Comment: @DJ there is only one String object. This is optimised by the compiler at compile time.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Compiler will optimize? then can I say String space will be cleaned when no reference? ( same as other objects )

Comment: The class code has a reference, so it has to be unloaded first.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I'm asking about `good` + `luck`

Comment: Those strings won't appear in the byte code, nor at runtime.